# Ubuntu is not detected after installing with Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, detect

I had Windows 7 installed on my laptop initially. Then I installed Ubuntu 14.04 with the option of "separate partition".

Installation was successful but when system restarts, it doesn't detect Ubuntu.

And the main issue is I am no longer able to see my D: drive where I had all my software.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Do you have UEFI or Legacy boot?

Comment: Sorry @SachinKamath what is that ?

Comment: @karel it is not duplicate of what you are posting In that windoes is installed after having ubuntu while my case is just opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start messing with the boot loader or grub of either OS try booting to windows and press the windows key + R  type msconfig in the command box and hit return. 
Click on the Boot tab check to see if Ubuntu is listed as an OS. If it is try making the Ubuntu installation the default (select Ubuntu 14.04 and click on the set as default button). Try to reboot into Ubuntu.

This would just be my first step. If this does not work get back to me.

As a side note:- Your D: drive going missing could be a few things but you have one of the most versatile tools in your Ubuntu USB. Just to see if the drive does still exist boot into Ubuntu Live using the USB and check the file structure of D: if it's still available try mounting it from your Ubuntu Live USB (at the worst you will get to save any data).

Comment: Okay bro I tried but in my listing there is only Windows7 not ubunutu.

Comment: Try  using 'Easy BCD' to add an entry to the windows boot loader, that points to Ubuntu's GRUB boot loader on the other partition. Easy BCD is free for none commercial use and runs under windows 7 so you should have no issues using it.

Comment: https://neosmart.net/Download/Register/1

Comment: I have installed now what ?

Comment: Start Windows and install the free version of EasyBCD. Open the EasyBCD program and select Add New Entry from the sidebar on the left. Select the rightmost tab, 'NeoGrub' under "Operating Systems" and click the Install button. Click on the Linux/BSD tab. Select GRUB2 as the type of entry, edit the name of the entry you are about to add to Windows Boot menu to whatever you like. Select 'Edit Boot Menu' from the sidebar to see the changes.
Save the changes and reboot. When the Windows boot menu appears, select the EasyBCD entry you added to boot Ubuntu..

Comment: I have done that I have installed NeroGrub

Comment: I have rebooted it.selected my entry now what ?

Comment: If you selected your entry and pressed return then you should have booted into the OS you pointed easybcd to (Ubuntu).

Comment: no it did not happen.I selected my entry and press "enter" It is showing GRUB>

Comment: Is the partition you used to instal Ubuntu visible to Windows?

Comment: no its not visible

Comment: I don't think the partition was set to root or made bootable. I think you will have to install Ubuntu again but instead of selecting ext4. as your partition you need to select the first option '/' It indicates a root directory. Also about 2.5 to 4gb swap partition wich is another option under the instalations disk management.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty hard drive through VMware

   1. Open VMware
   2. Click create a new virtual machine
   3. Select custom (advanced)
   4. Click next and again next
   5. Select I will install operating system later and click next
   6. Select Linux and select version of your MAIN OS
   7. Click next and select location and  select install.
2. Then create bootable USB and install in normal process. Your created disk will be identified.